# Apply isalpha to a list

Tags: python-3.x, function, text, nlp

i'm new to python. I have a NLP project and need to remove the frequencies from my keywords. I successsfully did it on one row i made into a list.

So the input: tokens= ['fibre',
 '16',
 ';',
 'quoi',
 '1',
 ';',
 'dangers',
 '1',]

using

```
tokens = [word for word in tokens if word.isalpha()
```

output is this 
['fibre', 'quoi', 'dangers', ]

Now i would like to apply this to the whole column. This is what I have:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize,sent_tokenize
tokens = cleaningkey.apply(word_tokenize)
tokens.head(5)
```

output:

```
0    [fibre, 16, ;, quoi, 1, ;, dangers, 1, ;, comb...
1               [restaurant, 1, ;, marrakech.shtml, 1]
2    [payer, 1, ;, faq, 1, ;, taxe, 1, ;, habitatio...
3    [rigaud, 3, ;, laurent, 3, ;, photo, 11, ;, pr...
4    [societe, 1, ;, disparition, 1, ;, proche, 1, ...
Name: text_norm, dtype: object
```

I tried different things but keep getting (list' object has no attribute 'isalpha'). Could someone tell me how to proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the test function to each item of the list:

```
cleaningkey.apply(lambda lst: [word for word in lst if word.isalpha()])
#0    [fibre, quoi, dangers]
#1              [restaurant]
```

Alternatively:

```
df.cleaningkey.apply(lambda lst: list(filter(str.isalpha, lst)))
#0    [fibre, quoi, dangers]
#1              [restaurant]
```

Comment: strange.. i got this output: 
cleaningkey.apply(lambda lst: list(filter(str.isalpha, lst)))
0        [f, i, b, r, e, q, u, o, i, d, a, n, g, e, r, ...
1        [r, e, s, t, a, u, r, a, n, t, m, a, r, r, a, ...
2        [p, a, y, e, r, f, a, q, t, a, x, e, h, a, b, ...

Comment: edit: it worked!! tokens.apply(lambda lst: [word for word in lst if word.isalpha()])  THANK YOU